# Abort asynchronous function from background proccess

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, cancellation

I have an asynchronous function that I would like to abort from a process that is running in the background.
The abortion does not need to cancel any promises that are currently pending inside of the asynchronous function.
It just needs to make the function return and prevent any further lines from getting executed.
How could I do this?
The current code does not work because the error is thrown inside setInterval instead of the try block.

```
setInterval(() => { //background proccess
  abort();
}, 5000); 

async function func() {
  try {
    abort = function thr() {
      throw new Error("dsaf");
    };
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
  } catch {
    console.log("caught");
  }  
}   

func()
```

Update: Are there other languages that support this type of pattern better or are all languages like this?

Comment: There is at least one big misconception here. `setInterval` is not a background process. Also, none of the awaited promises abort.

Comment: I don't know if the terminology was correct but it is a function that is always running without ever returning.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "always running without ever returning" function in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for

```
let throwIfAborted = () => {};

setInterval(() => { //background proccess
  throwIfAborted = () => { throw new Error("Abort"); };
}, 5000);

async function func() {
  try {
    throwIfAborted();
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    throwIfAborted();
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    throwIfAborted();
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    throwIfAborted();
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    throwIfAborted();
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    throwIfAborted();
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    throwIfAborted();
    await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    throwIfAborted();
  } catch {
    console.log("caught");
  }  
}   

func()
```

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do that though? Ideally even without using try-catch to short circuit?

Comment: @yyyyrrrrreee You can also use a boolean flag and write `if (aborted) return`, but there really isn't a nicer way to achieve this. (You say you didn't want to `clearTimeout` the currently active timeout - which would however leave the promise unresolved, which isn't a good idea either).

Comment: Oh yeah that is possible but is there a way to stop repeating ```throwIfAborted()``` or ```if (aborted) return```?

Comment: @yyyyrrrrreee No. If you want the possibility to abort a function after every statement, you have to check after every statement if the function should be aborted ...

Comment: Okay, do you know if there are other languages that support this type of pattern better, or are all languages like this?

Comment: @yyyyrrrrreee You can hack your way around this by using a generator function and `yield` instead of `await` - I've once [written a promise library](https://github.com/bergus/creed) that does support this. Other languages do this differently, Python e.g. has scriptable async/await syntax and [the `trio` library has superb cancellation](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: What would the code with yield look like?

Comment: @yyyyrrrrreee See [the example](https://github.com/bergus/creed/blob/cancellation/cancellation.md#coroutines) in the docs

Answer (score 0):

To make life easier, you could create a helper function.

Below I've created a simple abortable function, all you do then is put your async code inside a `run`, and then call `abort` when your ready.

eg.

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

function abortable() {
  let aborted = false;
  return {
    abort: () => aborted = true,
    run: async cb => {
      if (aborted) throw new Error('Aborted');
      return await cb();
    }
  }
}


async function hello(caption, ms) {
  await sleep(ms);
  return `Ran ${caption}`;
}


const {abort, run} = abortable();
setTimeout(() => abort(), 2000);

async function test() {
  try {
    console.log(await run(() => hello('One', 1500)));
    console.log(await run(() => hello('Two', 1500)));
    //this next one should not run, as it's over 2000ms
    console.log(await run(() => hello('Three', 1500)));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}

test();
```

Using generators, like in @Dmitriy's answer with CPromise's looks nice, only slight problem is that if the return value from the previous one is required for the next.  A simple solution here though is use some form of state and pass that to each function.

Below is an example using generators, but without any 3rd party lib.

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

function abortable() {
  let aborted = false;
  return {
    abort: () => aborted = true,
    run: async p => {
      for (const r of p()) {
        if (aborted) throw new Error('aborted');
        console.log(await r);
      }
    }
  }
}


async function hello(state, value, ms) {
  await sleep(ms);
  state.total += value;
  return `Total ${state.total}`;
}

const {abort, run} = abortable();
setTimeout(() => abort(), 2000);

run(function *() {
  const state = {total: 0};
  yield hello(state, 5, 1500);
  yield hello(state, 10, 1500);
  yield hello(state, 15, 1500);
}).catch(e => console.log(e.message));
```

Comment: @yyyyrrrrreee  It doesn't matter were you call the abort from, I've updated my snippet to put the abortable outside of the async function.

Comment: Sorry, this does work and is doing the same thing as Bergi's code but without repetition.

Comment: @yyyyrrrrreee In fact, it does have the the same repetition. It's just written differently. Instead of calling `throwIfAborted()` after every awaited function, you now call `run(() => something async)` multiple times. And this is doing exactly the same, ie check if the `abort` flag is set, and if yes, it throws an error ... Because that's the only way you can achieve, what you want. You have to check after every statement, if the current function should be aborted ...

Comment: Yes, that is true but written differently. Although I do think this is more readable though.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [CPromise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-promise2) package, this can be done as follows ([Live sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cpromise-cancel1-etxg7?file=/src/index.js)):

```
import { CPromise } from "c-promise2";

const func = CPromise.promisify(function* () {
  try {
    yield new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    yield new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    yield new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    yield new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    yield new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    yield new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
    yield new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 10000));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`caught: ${err}`);
  }
});

const promise = func();

setInterval(() => {
  promise.cancel();
}, 5000);
```